# Can't run go program using sudo command

Tags: go, amazon-s3

I am new to go programming language.

I am using below to packages in my my-s3zipper.go program.

```
"github.com/AdRoll/goamz/aws"
"github.com/AdRoll/goamz/s3"
```

When I run my go program with local user, its running fine. Below is the go run command.

```
go run my-s3zipper.go
Running on port 80
```

When I run my go program with sudo, its not running and throwing errors. Below is the go run command using sudo.

```
sudo go run my-s3zipper.go 



my-s3zipper.go:19:5: cannot find package "github.com/AdRoll/goamz/aws" in any of:
        /usr/lib/golang/src/github.com/AdRoll/goamz/aws (from $GOROOT)
        /root/go/src/github.com/AdRoll/goamz/aws (from $GOPATH)
my-s3zipper.go:20:5: cannot find package "github.com/AdRoll/goamz/s3" in any of:
        /usr/lib/golang/src/github.com/AdRoll/goamz/s3 (from $GOROOT)
        /root/go/src/github.com/AdRoll/goamz/s3 (from $GOPATH)
my-s3zipper.go:21:5: cannot find package "github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis" in any of:
        /usr/lib/golang/src/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis (from $GOROOT)
        /root/go/src/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis (from $GOPATH)
```

Any one can help me resolving this?

Thanks

Comment: sudo does not preserve environment variables by default in many distributions. You shouldn't compile as root anyway. Build the program as your user with `go build` or `go install`, then execute the compiled program with sudo. However, if it "works fine" without root, I really don't understand why you would do that.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for your comment. I was unaware that the "sudo does not preserve environment variables". In order to run my go program on port 80 I was trying to run in using sudo. BTW, I have figured out my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Lookup envkeep in sudoers is just use a high port like 3000 et al. Welcome to Go!

Comment: You should also never be compiling software as root. If you compile the program correctly in the first place, you no longer need to worry about `sudo` preserving the go env variables.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably work

```
sudo -E go run my-s3zipper.go
```

From the sudo man page

> -E' The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment
>   variables. The security policy may return an error if the -E option is
>   specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the
>   environment.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
sudo GOPATH="$GOPATH:/your/home/go/path" go run my-s3zipper.go
```

or

```
su
GOPATH="$GOPATH:/your/home/go/path"
go run my-s3zipper.go
```

The reason, probably, is that the GOPATH variable is different for your user and root.

You can detect `/your/home/go/path` by executing `echo $GOPATH` when you logged in your user

Comment: This is really bad advice. There is no reason to run go as root, and any kind of vulnerability in the tool chain is that much more severe if you do. See [CVE-2018-6574](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2018-6574/), [CVE-2018-7187](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2018-7187/), [CVE-2018-16873](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2018-16873/), [CVE-2018-16874](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2018-16874/), for instance.

Comment: I answered the question "how", not the "is it worth it". My answer can help to understand the reason why its script does not run.